# How can I replace a snapshot from the answers history?

Tags: support, revision-history

I want to replace a screenshot in an answer; I left some file paths in that screenshot.

I know how to blur out the information in the screenshot and edit my post. 
But how can I remove the revision history of my answer, so that the old screenshot is no longer visible to anyone that cares to look?

Comment: Flag the post with a custom moderator flag explaining what you want and why you want/need it.

Comment: I've gone ahead and done the redaction already.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to remove sensitive information from a post history, flag the post for moderator attention and explain why you need the history to be altered.

If a moderator agrees, they can *redact* the history of the post. The revision will still be there, just without the sensitive data.

When a moderator redacts a revision of a post, a second moderator needs to approve the change, so this process is not instant. Flagging your post, a moderator picking up the flag, and a second moderator approving the change all takes time, so if you accidentally left in API tokens or a username and password for a server, *change those as soon as possible*, because we can't guarantee that the revision has not already been seen by someone with malicious intent.

I've gone ahead and redacted the specific post that prompted your question; the redaction has been approved by another moderator and the old screenshot is no longer present in the post history.

Comment: If the screenshot was send to imgur your redaction didn't affect that, right? So in theory that screenshot can re-appear, either from a google cache or because someone *scrapes* imgur. I know this is very unlikely, still worth mentioning.

Comment: @rene: yes, in theory this is possible, but scraping would require brute-forcing all possible i.stack.imgur.com URLs; it statistically improbable that the unredacted image is ever found. A CM can request a imgur.com purge for a specific URL, but due to CDN caching and other factors deletion takes a very, very long time. It is also possible someone cached the previous revision elsewhere. This is why I added the specific disclaimer of replacing tokens and passwords ASAP, being more specific about imgur images is not really going to add anything.